# Trouble with count on a HAVING clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone help me with this query?

I need to select all the users only with everybody have dt_user_login = null,
if someone in the group have dt_user_login != null, i don't need **anyone.**

My query returns ORA-00937: not a single-group group function:

```
SELECT ID_USER
FROM USERS
WHERE ID_USER_GROUP = '003008'
  HAVING COUNT(ID_USER) = 
                ( SELECT COUNT(ID_USER) FROM USERS WHERE ID_USER_GROUP = '003008' AND DT_USER_LOGIN IS NOT NULL )
```

@Edit:
If in this group i have 5 users, and 1 of 5 users have dt_user_login = null, my query will not return **anyone** (0 users)

If in this group i have 5 users, and all of 5 users have dt_user_login = null, my query needs to return all the 5 users, got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may search for groups where there isn't a row with DT_USER_LOGIN is not null

```
SELECT U1.ID_USER
FROM USERS U1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM USERS U2 
                   WHERE U2.DT_USER_LOGIN IS NOT NULL
                     AND U1.ID_USER_GROUP = U2.ID_USER_GROUP
                  )
 AND U1.ID_USER_GROUP = '003008'
```

Comment: Edited my question with a example, if some user in the group have dt = null, i don't wanna return anyone.

Comment: In my query only if all the users in the group are null the query will return all those users. That's what you are looking for, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution using an analytic function to do the counting of not null dt_user_logins:

```
select id_user
from   (select id_user,
               id_user_group,
               count(case when dt_user_login is not null then 1 end) over (partition by id_user_group) not_null_dt_user_login_count
        from   users)
where  id_user_group = '003008'
and    not_null_dt_user_login_count = 0;
```

You should test all solutions to see which one works best for your data. Some may be more performant than others.

Comment: Unfortunately, returned ORA-00904: "id_user_group": invalid identifier
on line "where  id_user_group = '003008''"

Comment: Whoops, I missed that column out of the inner query. Have updated the query in my answer, so the it should work correctly now.